# Rails 4, Devise, Nested attributes not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activerecord

I am using devise for user authentication in a rails 4 app.

After the user registers, I am redirecting the user to a page which has some additional fields they can choose to populate. I have the form appearing correctly, but it is not saving the nested attribute to the database.

I have a model called "seeker_skill" which has this relation to user:

user has_many seeker_skills
seeker_skills belongs to user

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :seeker_skills, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seeker_skills, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:skill].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController< ApplicationController
    def job_seeker_additional_fields
        @user = current_user
        @user.seeker_skills.build 
        @seeker_skill = current_user.seeker_skills.build
    end
end
```

**seeker_skill.rb**

```
class SeekerSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :skill, presence: true
end
```

**seeker_skills_controller.rb**

```
class SeekerSkillsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @seeker_skill = current_user.seeker_skills.build(seeker_skill_params)
    if @seeker_skill.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash[:error] = "Invalid Input"
        redirect_to myskills_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def new
    @seeker_skill = current_user.seeker_skills.build
    @user = current_user
  end

  private

        def seeker_skill_params
            params.require(:seeker_skill).permit(:skill)
        end
end
```

I believe I have the permitted parameters set up correctly in the application controller.
**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :role, :email, 
      :company, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
      seeker_skills_attributes: [:id, :skill, :user_id, :_destroy]) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, 
      :username, :role, :email, :company, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :bio, 
      :min_salary, :location, :radius, :role, :email, :company, :password, :password_confirmation, 
      :current_password, seeker_skills_attributes:  [:id, :skill, :user_id, :_destroy]) }
  end

end
```

Finally there is the form in the view: Eventually I will add option to add multiple skills at once.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for(@seeker_skill) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :skill, placeholder: "Add skill" %>
<% end %>


<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing? I have set this up with a custom user authentication system but never with devise.

Comment: May be this post can help you https://coderwall.com/p/qwx3qa

Answer (score 0):

Change your nested fields call to:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:seeker_skill) do |f| %>
```

with a symbol, not the object. When created with object, it names the field from the object class name, so in result you got `params[:user][:seeker_skill]`, which are then filtered by strong params. While run with symbol, it tries to execute method with given name, treats it as an object and if the form object defines `<name>_attributes` sets the subobject name to `<name>_attributes`.